# Pytorch - Repeating Loss

Tags: pytorch, repeat, loss

I am new to PyTorch and I found a problem when displaying the loss of my model.
[Pytorch Adam Optimizer - Model Loss Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86lie.png)

[Pytorch SGD Optimizer - Model Loss Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6nVe.png)

As you can see, the model seem to go up and down multiple times, with a recurrent pattern (the pattern starting to repeat at the begging of every epoch).

The full code can be found at: https://github.com/19valentin99/Kaggle/tree/main/Iris%20Flowers
in main_test.py (the # lines are the ones that I used to debug the code and the answer should be below).

Answer (score 0):

> When we just take the loss of the last element (or the loss over the
> whole epoch) we will see a smooth decrease in loss

The reason your loss is smooth is because you are looking at the loss of the exact same batch on every iteration. Indeed your [train data loader](https://github.com/19valentin99/Kaggle/blob/main/Iris%20Flowers/main.py#L105) isn't shuffling your instance:

```
train2 = DataLoader(flowers_data_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

This means the same batch will appear last on every epoch. That's all there is to it, this doesn't mean the learning is different, it means you are looking at a part of the complete dataset loss.

Answer (score -1):

The difference between "not working" and "working" is based of **when the loss is recorded.** 
The idea is that: overall, the loss converges, but in this time until it converges it jumps up and down.
While it jumps up and down, we might see a pattern if we are sampling too often. The pattern is given by the data we use for training (as the data we use to train is the same every epoch - in batches).

As a result:
For the not-working version: I was recording the loss every epoch, after every batch. 
For the working version: I was recording only the latest loss in the epoch.

[Pytorch Adam Optimizer - Model Loss (working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paT3n.png)

[Pytorch SGD Optimizer - Model Loss (working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2SvT.png)

Furthermore, I will attach the code which generates the non working version:

```js
loss_list = []
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    for idx, (x, y) in enumerate(train_load):
        x, y = x.to(device), y.to(device)
        #Compute Error
        prediction = model(x)
        #print(prediction, y)
        loss = loss_fn(prediction, y)

        #debuging
        loss_list.append(loss.item())

        ##Backpropagation
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()


plt.plot(loss_list)
plt.show()
```

The working code:

```js
loss_list2 = np.zeros((EPOCHS,))
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    for batch, (x, y) in enumerate(train_load):
        x = x.to(device=device)
        y = y.to(device=device)
        y_pred = model(x)
        loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)
        loss_list2[epoch] = loss.item()

        # Zero gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    
    


plt.plot(loss_list2)
plt.show()
```

In the end, I would like to mention that I know that there are a couple of other threads out there that say how to solve this problem (like: clip the gradients, remove the last batch, model is too simple to capture the data) but in the end, what I discovered is that it wasn't actually a problem but more "when the recording of the data is done".

I hope that this will help other people as well.

Comment: So what you are saying is: replacing `loss_list.append(loss.item())` with `loss_list2[epoch] = loss.item()` makes the code "work"? The code you provided in the link doesn't run...

Comment: The code provided is "the part" which makes the difference between a smooth loss and one which looks random. With that code I wanted to illustrate that when the loss is capture after each bach, we will get a uneven loss (it goes up and down in a repetitive pattern).

Comment: When we just take the loss of the last element (or the loss over the whole epoch) we will see a smooth decrease in loss.